# How to check when ffmpeg completes a video segment?

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, process, file-writing

I'm using a ffmpeg Process from within my C# program. I start it off and run it in segmented mode.

```sh
ffmpeg -i rtsp://127.0.0.1/axis-media/media.amp?resolution=1280x720 -c copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 21600 -strftime 1 -reset_timestamps 1 -segment_format flv "C:\REPLACE_ME_WITH_REAL_DIRECTORY\%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.flv"
```

This creates a number of recording segments each in their own folder that are 6 hours long. I now need to be able to detect whether a file has started being written and whether it's completed being written as fast as possible to record it to a database. And this needs to work even in the face of crashes.

I'm polling the folder and can detect that a file has started being written. But detecting whether a file has completed is much trickier. Possibly can be done by polling whether or not a file is being written to. Does ffmpeg have some sort of support for this? Such as when it finishes a file it can launch another program or run a command?

I will occasionally scan through all the files and make sure that I record the ones that are there in case one is missed. But the more reliable, the better for this application.

Comment: Share full command.

Comment: Sorry, have some html open and close brackets to represent variables, which stack decided to remove. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the segment_list option that writes in a given file the finished segments. See https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html .